# Convert associative array from the result of mysqli_fetch_all to simple indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have code like this

```
 $years_of_service = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT YEAR(curdate())-Year_Entry FROM result");

 $result = mysqli_fetch_all($years_of_service,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

When i try to echo that result to see what happened with that code, i found this kind of array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 25 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 25 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 25 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 25 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 25 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [15] => Array ( [0] => 11 ) [16] => Array ( [0] => 11 ) [17] => Array ( [0] => 11 ) [18] => Array ( [0] => 11 ) [19] => Array ( [0] => 11 ) [20] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [21] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [23] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [24] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [25] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) [26] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) [27] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) [28] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) [29] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) [30] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) [31] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) [32] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) [33] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [34] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [35] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [36] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [37] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [38] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [39] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [40] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [41] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [42] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [43] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [44] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [45] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [46] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [47] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [48] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [49] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [50] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [51] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [52] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [53] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [54] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [55] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [56] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [57] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [58] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [59] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [60] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [61] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [62] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [63] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [64] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [65] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [66] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [67] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [68] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [69] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [70] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [71] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [72] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [73] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [74] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [75] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [76] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [77] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [78] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [79] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [80] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [81] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [82] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [83] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [84] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [85] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [86] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [87] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [88] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [89] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
```

I want to make it become a simple array containing only its value like

```
Array(25,25,25,....)
```

What is the best approach i can use. I've tried to make it simple array with this

```
$simple = array_values($result);
```

But it did'nt work. It show the same output with $result. I will use it for map and reduce function to categorize years of service by specific range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is you're retrieving all rows (outer array) which are being returned as an array of columns (the inner arrays).

What you need to do is loop through the rows:

```
$years_of_service = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT YEAR(curdate())-Year_Entry FROM result");
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($work_period,MYSQLI_NUM);

$data = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row[0];
}
```

Your array will now be 'flat':

```
$data => [
    0 => 25,
    1 => 24,
    ...
];
```

which will now return what you want when you use `array_values`:

```
$simple = array_values($data); // $simple will now equal Array(25, 24, ...)
```

Comment: Almost work. Work great until I am failed using array_values(). No idea why it did'nt work. When I print_r on somewhere , it's $simple array shows the same array with $data.

Comment: It is no problem now. I can proceed my work without that $simple array. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If **`PHP > 5.5.0`** you can simply use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like as

```
$result = array_column($your_array,0);
```

or you can simply use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) like as

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge',$your_array);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/jFKdr)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$simple = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $simple[] = $value[0];
}
```

Comment: It's give me Array() that has no value